# Canvas. Взаимодействие с dom элементами на странице.

Tags: canvas, javascript, html, dom

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

Сразу скажу, что с canvas почти не знаком, но очень хочу познакомиться.

Вопрос:

Есть вот такая вот ссылка http://m-ms.dk/spaceheroes/.

Уделите, пожалуйста, 5 минут Вашего времени и посмотрите что там.
Если проделать все то, что там просят, то появляется возможность с помощью их скрипта взаимодействовать (если я правильно понял) с dom элементами на любой странице.

Очень хочется узнать как они это сделали? Это нативная возможность canvas? Или canvas берет страницу и перерисовывает её "в себе" и потом работает с ней, как со своей сущностью? В какую сторону смотреть и копать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

открываем http://www.m-ms.dk/spaceheroes/js/spaceship.js

смотрим в 409ю строку, в этой функции используется `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);` т.к. `canvas` растянут на весь экран, то координаты выстрела совпадают (не всегда, например можно дебагом сделать пропуски) с координатами элемента, далее уже дело техники, вычислить можно ли разбивать этот элемент и "разбить" его.